# Number format doesn't work in Smarty's foreach

Tags: php, smarty, number-formatting

I would like to separate some numbers in thousands, but *number_format* doesn't work in this foreach loop inside input's value:

```
{foreach $uab_list as $uab}
      <label for="uab_{$uab.level}">UAB {$uab.name}</label>
      <input type="number" name="uab_{$uab.level}" value="{$uab.price|number_format:0:',':'.'}">
{/foreach}
```

and no values being produce, but numbers are showing up when number_format modifier being omitted.

Can't anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{$uab.price|number_format:0:',':'.'}
```

It is correct format. Do you get output without this number formating? Just value: {$uab.price} ???

Check tag `{foreach} - {foreach from=$uab_list item=uab}`
[Manual](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.foreach.tpl)

Comment: Yes, I get output from  {$uab.price} .

Comment: Try formating outside foreach on separate value: {$price1|number_format:0:',':'.'}

Comment: I tried in a single value, and it works. But in a loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check tag {foreach} - {foreach from=$uab_list item=uab} You got wrong syntax

Comment: Both have the same result, with or without modifier.

Comment: I finally get where I'm wrong. Input's type 'number' prevents a formatting number. I have to use 'text' type if I want a formatting number in an input's value.
Thank you @Vladimir for accompanying me.

Comment: You welcome. Yes input type="number" 
formats a number in its own way.